# How to embed YouTube video found on a site on my website

Tags: youtube, embed

I would like to extract the video from [this website](http://buxoff.com/suggest-store/) and post it on my blog. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the video title, it will take you to YouTube. Then click on Share button, grab the embed link and paste it on your blog.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the embed code for that particular video. I'm not sure why, but on my computer it was asking for a plugin to view it. I just pulled the URL out of the HTML code and was able to open it on YouTube and generate the embed code through the sites sharing options.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/7T6xcvyb7to" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```